# How can I fix 'MongoParseError: Multiple text records not allowed at ...' on MongoDB connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

*it's the first times I write here and I don't speak English well, so if I'm wrong please critics in a good way.*

So, the problem is that **when I restart** my node.js after having already started it, **I get this error** and I have to wait like 10/20 sec to restart and get the db connection.

**ERROR:**

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Not Connected:  { MongoParseError: Multiple text records not allowed
    at QueryReqWrap.dns.resolveTxt [as callback] (/Users/guy/Desktop/Progetto PWM/progetto/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/uri_parser.js:93:27)
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:198:10)
  name: 'MongoParseError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

I am following a video tutorial that explains basics on **Nodejs** connection with MongoDB and these are my dependencies:

```
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"dotenv": "^8.0.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"mongoose": "^5.6.7",
"morgan": "^1.9.1"
```

and my **.env** file contains:

```
MONGO_URI= mongodb+srv://<name>:<password>@myproject-0aqq2.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

where inside brackets there are my data.

**EDIT**

this is the code I used to connect

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log("Connected"))
.catch(err => {
  console.log("Not Connected: ", err);
});
```

Comment: how are you connecting to mongodb? Can you show your connection code? also are you using mongodb replicas? If not, you can remove the query params from your connection string after **?**

Comment: I added the code that I'm using; what do you mean with Mongodb replicas? I'm using MongoDB Atlas

Comment: Did you tried removing the options from connection string. If not try changing your connection string as **mongodb+srv://<name>:<password>@myproject-0aqq2.mongodb.net/test**

Comment: @MohammedAmirAnsari Yes I tried but the error still appears

Comment: How about removing {useNewUrlParser: true} or making it false. As this is the place where i think parsing error is thrown

Comment: Also if you are not using replicas, why have you added **+srv** in your connection string??

Comment: In the MongoDB site, when I went to request the string connection, it give me that. If I remove **+srv** it fail to connect, while if remove or set **false** the parameter it give me error followed by the MongoParseError

Comment: @AndreaAnfuso I have this problem also! It's highly annoying... I have tried deleting the DB and setting it up again, deleting the Cluster and setingt it up again (new DB and user), and removing nodemon from the start script - same problems

Comment: If you dig down into the error you arrive at https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-core/blob/b9205e632c3b98a8834c52a5d33560e1a6e1d592/lib/uri_parser.js#L93 , so I assume its something to do with how we configure our cluster urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this issue is to use the [Standard Connection String Format for Sharded Clusters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)
as specified in the documentation:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@mongos0.example.com:27017,mongos1.example.com:27017,mongos2.example.com:27017/admin
```

*@mongos0.example.com:27017* is to be replace with the primary host name, with the 2 secondary hosts following that. You can get the addresses and ports for the 3 hosts in the Cluster Overview in the Altas Web Interface. Be sure to replace the /admin with the name of your database to which you wish to connect.

This is the recommended String Connection Format (3.4) to be used with mongoose - I checked this with the mongo support people, who were very helpful!

Comment: Thank you for the answer! First of all I tried to change che connection string as you mentioned, but it wasn't working the same; but seeing the connection string of NodeJs 2.12.12 was very similar to yours, I tried it and it worked!

Comment: The string have this after database name now: **?ssl=true&replicaSet=MyCluster-shard-0&authSource=adminDB&retryWrites=true&w=majority**